# Issues with Ajax Pagination and Filtering

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax, pagination

I am creating a website and just can't manage to get the pagination to update when a filter is selected.

block.php

```
<section class="photographers full-width-grid mt-<?= $attributes['margin-top']; ?> mb-<?= $attributes['margin-bot']; ?>">
    <div class="filter-container photographers-filter d-grid">
        <?php
        $photographer_cat_terms = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'kategorie',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ));

        $bundesland_terms = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'bundesland',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ));
        ?>

        <select class="photographer-cat" name="photographer-cat">
            <option value="">Kategorie</option>
            <?php foreach ($photographer_cat_terms as $term) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

        <select class="photographer-location" name="photographer-location">
            <option value="">Bundesland</option>
            <?php foreach ($bundesland_terms as $term) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="photographers-container d-grid" id="photographers-container">
    <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'photographers',
        'paged'     => $paged,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
        ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="photographer-single">
                <div class="photographer-thumbnail img-container">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="photographer-name sub-headline"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            </a>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
    ?>
        <div class="no-photographers">Keine Fotografen gefunden</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ( $query->max_num_pages > 1 ) { ?>
        <div class="pagination-container">
            <?php 
            echo paginate_links( array(
                'base'    => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => max( 1, $paged ),
                'total'   => $query->max_num_pages,
            ) );
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</section>
```

functions.php

```
function handle_filtering_ajax() {
    $category = isset($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : '';
    $location = isset($_GET['location']) ? $_GET['location'] : '';
    $paged = isset($_GET['paged']) ? $_GET['paged'] : 1;

    $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');

    if (!empty($category)) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'kategorie',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $category,
        );
    }

    if (!empty($location)) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'bundesland',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $location,
        );
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'photographers',
        'tax_query'      => $tax_query,
        'paged'          => $paged, // Pass the current page number
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="photographer-single">
                <div class="photographer-thumbnail img-container">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="photographer-name sub-headline"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            </a>
        <?php
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        echo 'Keine Fotografen gefunden.';
    }

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_handle_filtering', 'handle_filtering_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_handle_filtering', 'handle_filtering_ajax');
```

main.js

```
filterHelper = () => {
    function handlePagination(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(link, function(data) {
            var $container = $('.photographers-container');
            var photographers = $(data).find('.photographers-container').html();
            var pagination = $(data).find('.pagination-container').html();

            $container.html(photographers);
            $('.pagination-container').html(pagination);

            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.photographers').offset().top - $('.site-header').outerHeight() - 50
            }, '250');

            $('.pagination-container a').on('click', handlePagination);
        });
    }

    $('.pagination-container').on('click', 'a', handlePagination);

    function handleFiltering(category, location, page) {
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_obj.ajax_url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                action: 'handle_filtering',
                category: category,
                location: location,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('.photographers-container').html(response);
                $('.pagination-container a').on('click', handlePagination);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(xhr, status, error);
            }
        });
    }

    $('.photographer-cat, .photographer-location').change(function() {
        var category = $('.photographer-cat').val();
        var location = $('.photographer-location').val();
        handleFiltering(category, location, page);
    });
}
```

Comment: if it doesn't do what you expected to do, what does it do instead? Do you mean it updates with exactly the same results as if no filter was selected? Or no request is made? Or the wrong results are returned? Or it filters correctly but breaks pagination? Where does ` filterHelper` get called? I can see it being assigned in your code but not where it's being used